# vue getters not loading for first time with app launch and loading only afterwards

Tags: vue.js, getter

When I am loading a getter that returns an id in computed property. I try to print the 'id' in a method, the id value is empty for the first time when app loads. But then, when i edit a file and save I can see this id is getting printed in console. Or when I do setTimeout of 1 sec, I can see the getter.

This 'id' value is important and I want to access as a global variable. I want it access crop id right when app load. Because based on this value I will be making a few api calls.

The crop id is set from result of a api call.

`store.commit("setCropId", list.id);`

My vuex

```
state:{
    crop: ""
},
mutations: {
    setCropId(state, value) {
      state.crop = value;
    }
},
actions:{
    actionCropId ({ commit }, value) {
     commit('setCropId', value)
    }
},
getters: {
    getCropId: state => {
      return state.crop;
    }
}
```

My vue component

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getCropId',
    ])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myCrops();
  },
  methods: {
    async myCrops() {
     console.log('my crops', getCropId)
     // other logic
    }
  }
```

I dont know how to make it work. Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong or how to get getters right away when app loads.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an API, that is initialized asynchronously, inside a Vuex state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767946/how-to-use-an-api-that-is-initialized-asynchronously-inside-a-vuex-state)

Comment: ... or this? [How to load all server side data on initial vue.js / vue-router load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572974/how-to-load-all-server-side-data-on-initial-vue-js-vue-router-load)

Comment: the api call is made in router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // my api call then  store.commit("setCropId", list.id);
});   This is fine but its the getters not showing up when call in method in my component right after loading app

Comment: In your async myCrops method are you calling  actionCropId  action with await for getting corpId from api response?

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty no, u mean store.dispatch('actionCropId') ? I thought this was not necessary because my getter is set  in router before the component loads. So it would be just fetching the getter and not calling the action. Am I wrong?

Comment: From whatever code you have here i think its because you are consoling getCropId before its getting commited in store. check your async await action call.

Comment: @KalleshwarKalshetty ok I will, thank you, I suspect the lifecycle is like that